# Can not Read CyrptoJS Generated JWT using JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken()

Tags: javascript, c#, jwt

I am generating a token using CyrptoJS which correctly encodes and decodes in jwt.io test form. Using HMACSha256.

The process throws the exception:

```
IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed: '[PII is hidden]'.
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. 
(JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. 
(JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
```

Token received in api is :
eyAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwgInR5cGUiOiJKV1QifQ==.eyAiYWN0b3IiOiAiam9uZXMiLCAibmFtZSI6ICJDYXNlRWRpdCJ9.JRi5hfqItl2gne1dUJxq1dfgdgJ1zD9xn2aUJopglbI=

The code I am using to Validate the token is:

```
public static Boolean ValidateToken(string jwtToken,  string key)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
        };
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var claimPrincipal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

        return validatedToken.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the encoding from CryptoJS this helped me sort it out https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2014/11/27/creating-json-web-token-in-javascript.html I was not url encoding the values. removing the =